Верификация для загрузки через Youtube DATA API
Делаю приложение не для публичного пользования (для команды из нескольких человек, до 15 видео в день) для загрузки видео на один аккаунт youtube. Для прохождения верификации требуется публичная страница и тп. Как пройти верификацию для такого проекта или немного увеличить квоты без верификации?
Приложение "external", т.к. "internal" требует Организацию (не хотелось бы оплачивать Workspace ради этой одной функции).
